# Asking BlackBerry PIN to use inside the app

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde

Is there anyway to access the BlackBerry PIN inside my app? I would like to have a way to give certain devices unique access to certain things. If the PIN will not work, is there some other sort of unique identifier that would work and I can access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DeviceInfo.getDeviceId()` in the `net.rim.device.api.system` package will return the unique Blackberry PIN of the device as an `int`. However, keep in mind the simulator will return `0x2100000a` by default unless you change it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Have you took a look in the [API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html)

```
DeviceInfo.getDeviceId()
```